# Section content goes out of page on adding cards

Tags: html, css, height, viewport

I tried to display information in form of cards. Each cards is inside ordered list li. On adding more card in form of li, the content goes out of page from top. How can I set the height to adjust automatically according to the number of cards.

Html code

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="leftBox">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Events</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae quia atque cupiditate commodi
                    nihil
                    cum? Autem rem voluptates aperiam. Est non dolor, unde quam laborum eveniet quidem doloribus
                    iure
                    ad!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="events">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="time">
                        <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h3>Celestial</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere
                            deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="time">
                        <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h3>Celestial</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere
                            deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #323a45;
    background-size: cover;
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used display flex property to create cards element, it seems like you have used float element because of float it creates height alignment issue. We provide you two alignment structure so you can use any of according to your convenience.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/1vLqr6uo/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* background: #323a45;*/
  background-size: cover;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.events.copy ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="leftBox">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae quia atque cupiditate commodi nihil cum? Autem rem voluptates aperiam. Est non dolor, unde quam laborum eveniet quidem doloribus iure ad!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="events">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus
                maxime.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="events copy">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="time">
              <h2>2<br><span>April</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3>Celestial</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus
                maxime.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nam veritatis facere deleniti corporis deserunt doloribus maxime.
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#">View Details</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```